# find the general solution(ode)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Isn't the general solution yh + yp? What am I doing wrong? Got everything else correct, but stuck on question d.

Comment: Did you forgot $e^t$ (it should be $t^2 e^t$)

Comment: I entered $$ c1e^t + c2te^t -2t + c1 -t^2e^t + c2$$ and it's still wrong

Comment: What about that $2t$? where does it come from?

Comment: $$c1e^t + c2te^t -2te^t + c1 -t^2e^t + c2$$  is incorrect

Comment: Well, at least you will need to tel us how you get the y_p.

Comment: $$Y_H= c1e^t + te^t$$, $$Y_P= -2t - t^2$$?

Comment: Yes, but how do you get the $y_p$?

Comment: Doesn't the yp come from adding the integral?

Comment: Ar... no. You may check the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second-order_equation) or your own note.

Comment: Ok its y1u1 + u2y2

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

To start with, rearrange the given ODE in the following manner

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime} - 2y^{\prime} + y = (y^{\prime} - y)^{\prime} - (y^{\prime} - y)
\end{align*}

Then make the substitution $u = y^{\prime} - y$, which reduces the problem to solving a first order ODE twice.

Comment: I think I did all that in part a,b,c.

Answer (score -1):

The given answer is not correct.

Your $$y_h = c_1e^t+c_2te^t$$ is correct but the $y_p$ is not .
To find $y_p$ they used the method of variation of parameters as explained in the solution but they have their $y_p$  incorrect. The correct $y_p=-t^2e^t$ does not need the $c_1$ and $c_2$ but it uses $u_1e^t+u_2te^t$ where $u_1$  and $u_2$ are  found by the integrals.

The correct answer is $$y=  c_1e^t+c_2te^t -t^2e^t $$